# CRUD on single page Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I would like to do create update and delete on a single page on rails.

I am looking into backbone-rails at https://github.com/codebrew/backbone-rails

But I'm not sure how I should use it in achieving what I want to do.

Eventually, I would like to have a text field to signify whether it is an update, delete or create followed by a form with the following fields.
For creation, the form would be empty.
For updates, there should be links at the side where one can click and after which the form would be loaded.

I wish for it to happen without page reloading as well.

I am new to web programming and any kind of advice on what technologies I should be looking into would be appreciated.

Comment: Rails + AJAX are the technologies you need !

Comment: Everything you described is quite doable with Backbone. Look at its Todo example and move from there. But yeah, knowing Rails basics and what Ajax is definitely won't hurt.

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to agree with the above comments.

On top of ruby on rails, you will want to learn the basics of javascript, and jquery, and use [backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/) , (which is built on jquery and another library called [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/)).

The ToDo list that Dmitry mentioned is a good example and it has annotated source code:
[LiveApp](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/examples/todos/index.html) , [SourceCode](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/todos.html)

I also found this [nettuts backbone tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/sessions/build-a-contacts-manager-using-backbone-js/) very helpful when learning backbone
(they also have some great tutorials on javascript and jquery if you want to bone up on those too). Once you get the client side stuff working with backbone, then it's matter of hooking it up with your rails backend (the backbone rails gem might help tho I've never used it)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! It's just I am new to web programming and these technologies are a little overwhelming. I am starting with learning javascript and jquery. Will look into what you have suggested as well.

Comment: Definitely HTML CSS javascript jquery backbone ruby rails oh my! Its a lot of stuff.  But you are right working on some javascript and jquery would probably be the best place to start (well after basic html css :))